# Creating a database link from Oracle Cloud server to remote access database

Tags: oracle, ms-access, remote, database-link, oracle-apex

I work for a small company that currently use Apex to run reports on our accounts system. Oracle is installed on our local server and part of the data is gained via a database link to an access database.

We are changing our server and I was interested in trying out the Always Free cloud service to recreate the above.

Can anyone give me any pointers on if/how you could connect the cloud service to an access database held on of local server?

Please let me know what crucial information is missing from my question - I am sure there is some!

Any advice would be gratefully received.

Cheers

Andrew

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In theory yes, you could set up such a link, but I'm not sure I'd advise it. You would need an Oracle Gateway server on your local network to bridge the connection. You will also need direct network connectivity from the cloud to your Gateway server, which means opening your local firewall to allow the inbound connection from the internet. It would imply that you have a pretty robust network/secure infrastructure to support something like that.

See here: https://blogs.oracle.com/datawarehousing/making-database-links-from-adw-to-other-databases

or here: https://conferences.heanet.ie/assets/files/Thursday_B_11.00_Dick_Doyle_UCD.pdf

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I’m not sure we have sufficient security knowledge to risk this - thanks for saving me the time and potential issues!